# SAS macro loop aggregate output tables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro function defined as below.

```
%macro sqlloop(event_id, empl_nbr_var, fleet, base, position);
...lots of code...
%mend;
```

this macro creates a table called `export_table2` that i want to stack on top of each other for all of the times I run this code. I tried below

```
data executed;
set work.vars;
call execute('%sqlloop(17,'||strip(empl_nbr_var)||','||strip(fleet)||','||strip(base)||','||strip(position)||');');
run;

data summary_pilots;
set work.export_table2 summary_pilots;
run;
```

but this gives an error since summary_pilots doesnt exist as I'm trying to reference it. I also tried a weird work around where I took out the first row of `vars` into a new table and deleted it from the old, then tried executing below code (where row1 is the first row and vars is everything except the first row).

```
data _null_;
    set Work.row1;
    call execute('%sqlloop(17,'||strip(empl_nbr_var)||','||strip(fleet)||','||strip(base)||','||strip(position)||');');
run;

data summary_pilots;
set work.export_table2;
run;


data executed;
set work.vars;
call execute('%sqlloop(17,'||strip(empl_nbr_var)||','||strip(fleet)||','||strip(base)||','||strip(position)||');');
run;

data summary_pilots;
set work.export_table2 summary_pilots;
run;
```

and it still doesnt function quite as I want. This only includes the first table (from row1) and the very last table generated by the macro. I can see why it does this, since call execute is running them all at once and writing over any old tables, but I still dont know how to fix it. Any attempt to put it inside the earlier data step has failed as well. any suggestions?

Comment: Use PROC APPEND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the code to append needs to go inside `%sqlloop`, if possible.  If not, make a wrapper macro around %sqlloop, something like

```
%macro write_loop(parameters...);
  %sqlloop (parameters)
  
  data summary_pilots... ;
  run;
%mend write_loop;
```

Then `call execute` that.  You could also add a second `call execute` line, but that's unnecessarily complex.  There's also ways to do the `%sqlloop` that could possibly give you a single dataset instead of row-wise datasets, which would be best most likely in many situations.  There's also the possibility of giving a unique dataset for each `%sqlloop` execution.  I like the inclusion into the macro for most cases where a single dataset doesn't work, but there are reasons you might prefer unique datasets.

Second, you have a bunch of options, depending on details, for how to make the whole thing work.  `PROC APPEND` is a good start, as Tom noted in comments; that works if the dataset you're appending is always columnwise identical to what's been there before.

```
proc append base=summary_pilots data=export_table2;
quit;
```

That will create `summary_pilots` the first time it's run.  This only really works if the columns always match - sounds like that's likely?  `FORCE` option is also possible but it mostly isn't useful for this sort of thing unless you guarantee the first dataset is the complete dataset variable-wise.

If they don't match, then you are left with running, before anything else:

```
data summary_pilot;
  stop;
run;
```

Don't try to open it of course - it won't open, it has no rows and no columns - but it exists, and can be your "base".  You could also define the columns in it if you have a good "template"; I do this for some projects.

Comment: This all assumes, by the way, that your solution via `sqlloop` is the right solution - it can be, but most of the time it isn't; but you didn't say what you're doing, so I can't tell.